# CRUD in MVVM in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am new in MVVM. I have developed Windows phone 8 and WP8.1 app in normal way. But not with MVVM. I have search a lot but did not get any example which can make better understand of MVVM. I know what is MVVM. It is similarly of  MVC of Asp.net.

**MVVM** is

**Model** : Which describe data

**View-Model** : In simple word a bridge between Model and View.

**View** : A simple xaml page or user interface.

And I found links [Separate UI and app logic using the Model-View-ViewModel pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj721615(v=vs.105).aspx) and [Implementing the Model-View-ViewModel pattern for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153(v=vs.105).aspx)

But I need a example of **MVVM in WP8 with SQLite CRUD ( Insert, Select, Update and Delete ) operation**

Thank You,

Answer (score 1):

There are ample links on the Web that can lead you to good tutorials on MVVM with Windows Phone.

Here are a few:

[Practical MVVM For Windows Phone](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Practical-MVVM-For-Windows-Phone)

[An Address Book Made in MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/391783/An-Address-Book-Application-Made-in-MVVM-For-Metro)

[SQLite with a bit of MVVM Light in Windows Phone 8](http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2013/01/29/SQLite-in-Windows-Phone-8.aspx)